# Bin average as a function of position

Tags: python, numpy

I want to efficiently calculate the average of a variable (say temperature) over multiple areas of the plane.

I essentially want to do the following.

```
import numpy as np
num = 10000

XYT = np.random.uniform(0, 1, (num, 3))
X = np.transpose(XYT)[0]
Y = np.transpose(XYT)[1]
T = np.transpose(XYT)[2]

size = 10 
bins = np.empty((size, size))

for i in range(size):
    for j in range(size):
        if rescaled X,Y in bin[i][j]:
            bins[i][j] = mean T
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use pandas (although im sure you can achieve basically the same with vanilla numpy)

```
df = pandas.DataFrame({'x':npX,'y':npY,'z':npZ})
# solve quadrants
df['quadrant'] = (df['x']>=0)*2 + (df['y']>=0)*1
# group by and aggregate
mean_per_quadrant = df.groupby(['quadrant'])['temp'].aggregate(['mean'])
```

you may need to create multiple quadrant cutoffs to get unique groupings

for example `(df['x']>=50)*4 + (df['x']>=0)*2 + (df['y']>=0)*1` would add an extra 2 quadrants to our group (one y>=0, and one y<0) (just make sure you use powers of 2)

[image]